# Certificate generator with name , paper id and title

Tags: python, certificate

i am trying to make a ceritifcate generator , that picks up name and paper id from an excel sheet and print it on a jpeg file  and saving it as a pdf.
the prog i have is just taking the last (one) name from the excel file.
how to include all three ( or n number ) names. also how can we include paper id ( also paper title) in the certificate .
This is the code i have
feedback_form.xlsx is the file name from which it retreives name and title, cert.jpg is the sample certificate

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import pandas as pd
form = pd.read_excel("feedback_form.xlsx")
name_list = form['Name'].to_list()
for i in name_list:
im = Image.open("cert.jpg")
d = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
location = (725,549)
text_color = (0, 177, 209)
font = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 50)
d.text(location, i, fill=text_color,font=font)
im.save("certificate_"+ i + ".pdf")
```

Comment: So what's your problem?

Comment: my problems are 1- the prog is printing only last name in the name_list , i need the prog to print all the names given in the excel sheet , also i want to include paper id and  paper title in the certificate

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: need to generate certificate in bulk , with Author name , and its paper id. The prog i have, is producing  a single pdf file with just "Author Name " written on it . I need a programme that generates certificates for all author , given in the list also i need to have the paper id in the certificate as well. hope its clear now